# Convertir fecha de Datetime a Date sin alterar la estructura de la tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Estoy creando una consulta para obtener el valor sumado de todos los abonos de un crédito entre periodos determinados. Para esto tengo lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  @ValorPagado = SUM(Valor)
from    abono
WHERE   id_credito = @IdCredito
and fecha_pago <= @fechaCorte
```

Sucede que algunos de estos abonos registran `fecha_pago` de la siguiente manera:

> > `2019-04-04 19:54:01.000` y `2019-04-01 00:00:00.000`

lo que requiero hacer es construir una forma para indicarle, que todos las fechas de pago me lleguen en formato `Date` es decir `2019-04-04` sin la hora, así en la tabla tengan hora

Comment: Puedes explicar para qué quieres ese cambio?, estás haciendo un filtro sobre esa columna, por lo que no entiendo correctamente por qué quieres cambiarle el formato

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realiza un select con convert date y listo

tu codigo quedaria mas o menos asi, espero que te funcione,

```
SELECT  @ValorPagado = SUM(Valor)
from    abono
WHERE   id_credito = @IdCredito
and (CONVERT(date, fecha_pago, 103)) <= @fechaCorte
```

Answer (score 4):

Otra forma sencilla:

```
SELECT  @ValorPagado = SUM(Valor)
        from    abono
        WHERE   id_credito = @IdCredito
                and fecha_pago < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @fechaCorte)
```

Simplemente le sumamos un día a `@fechaCorte` y la consulta entonces la deberíamos hacer por menor (`<`).

Comment: muchas gracias @Patricio

Comment: @Fernankin según el interesante [comentario de Lamak](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/251916/convertir-fecha-de-datetime-a-date-sin-alterar-la-estructura-de-la-tabla/251922#comment468054_251922) en mi respuesta, esta de Patricio es la consulta más óptima, porque al dejar limpia la columna `fecha_pago`  ésta podrá ser beneficiada por las bondades del optimizador en todos los sentidos. El asunto es más grave si usaras consultas del tipo `JOIN`. Vi en post donde explicaban que aún en resultados vacíos la consulta leía `N` filas tan sólo por aplicar una función a columnas en el `WHERE`

Answer (score 3):

`SQL Server 12+` introdujo una nueva función **[`FORMAT()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** para formatear todo tipo de datos, incluyendo las fechas.

Su uso es muy simple, como las habituales funciones `format` de los lenguajes conocidos. En el primer parámetro la fecha, y en el segundo el tipo de formato deseado.

Haciendo esto obtendrás lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT  
    @ValorPagado = SUM(Valor)
FROM    abono
WHERE   id_credito = @IdCredito
        AND FORMAT(fecha_pago,'yyyy-MM-dd') <= @fechaCorte
```

Para más detalles puedes ver: [*Format SQL Server Dates with FORMAT Function*](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2655/format-sql-server-dates-with-format-function/)

---

Dado que al parecer lo que quieres es comparar sólo por fechas, ignorando la parte del tiempo, una opción interesante puede ser usar **[`TRY_CAST()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** (también introducida en SQL Server 2012+). Por medio de ella puedes convertir la fecha al [tipo de dato `DATE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) simplemente, ignorando de ese modo la parte de la hora. La ventaja de esta función es que en el caso de valores erróneos, maneja el código de forma que no ocurra un crash en el flujo del programa.

```
SELECT  
    @ValorPagado = SUM(Valor)
FROM    abono
WHERE   id_credito = @IdCredito
        AND TRY_CAST(fecha_pago AS DATE) <= TRY_CAST(@fechaCorte AS DATE)
```

Puede que esta forma sea más segura, sobre todo si `@fechaCorte` es una cadena.

Comment: En general no es conveniente usar una función sobre la columna que se está usando para filtrar, ya que evita que el optimizador pueda usar un posible índice que tenga la columna. En casos de fechas, lo mejor es simplemente usar una condición diferente en el filtro....por ejemplo: `AND fecha_pago < DATEADD(DAY,1,@fechacorte)`

Comment: @Lamak tu apunte es interesante, de hecho no lo sabía. Creo que sería bueno que aportes una respuesta explicándolo con más detalle. Es bueno conocer ese tipo de cosas que los no expertos es SQL ignoramos.

Comment: @Lamak encontré este artículo tratando de verificar lo que decías en tu comentario: [*SQL SERVER – Avoid Using Function in WHERE Clause – Scan to Seek*](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/03/12/sql-server-avoid-using-function-in-where-clause-scan-to-seek/). Es impresionante la cantidad de filas que son leídas aún en consultas que luego no traen datos. Era algo que ignoraba totalmente. Creo que sería interesante abordar de alguna forma el tema aquí en Stacoverflow.